# Script in dynamic SQL for Data Validation when there is multiple source and target

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql, dynamic-sql

There are more than 18 source systems, which are the real source of data.

All the source systems have a different schema.

The target tables were built on SQL Server.

The column name in the target table is different than the source table, that is the reason to use Master table for knowing schema of Source and Target table.

Currently there is no validation process, which confirms that the data loaded into the target is correct.

How to create sql script **either using c# or dynamic sql**, using MASTER and Driver Table.

MASTER table specifies mapping between two tables:

DRIVER table specifies for which source the script of comparison actually is to be executed:

Table Structure:

```
DECLARE @MASTERS TABLE (
    SourceInputtable VARCHAR (100),          
    Source_Column VARCHAR (100),             
    Target_Table VARCHAR (100),   
    Target_Column VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT @MASTERS
SELECT 'SRC_IBM',          'Webstore',        'TRANSACTION_HEADER',              'transaction_location_id' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_IBM',          'CustomerID',    'TRANSACTION_HEADER',              'customer_account_id'     UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_IBM',          'OrderType',      'TRANSACTION_HEADER',              'transaction_type_code'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_IBM',          'IP_Short_Sku',  'TRANSACTION_HEADER',      'ip_short_sku' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_IBM',          'SOURCEID',       'TRANSACTION_HEADER', 'TARGETID' UNION ALL
 
SELECT 'SRC_ClickStream',           'email_emailaddress',              'CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT',             'email_address' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_ClickStream',           'customer_signupdate',              'CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT',             'cust_update' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_ClickStream',           'TypeCode',             'CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT','TypeCode' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_ClickStream',           'AlternateID',          'CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT','AlternateID' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SRC_ClickStream',           'SOURCEID',                    'CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT', 'TARGETID'
 
SELECT * FROM @MASTERS
```

There is another table called as Driver with only 1 column

The Driver table always has only single value.

```
CREATE TABLE Driver (
    Source_for_Validation VARCHAR (100)
)

Insert Driver
Select 'SRC_IBM'
```

Sample Data

```
    DECLARE @IBM_SRC TABLE (
        Webstore VARCHAR (50),
        CustomerID VARCHAR (50),
        OrderType VARCHAR (50),
        IP_Short_Sku VARCHAR (50),
        SOURCEID VARCHAR (50)    
    )
    
    INSERT @IBM_SRC    
    SELECT 'ABC', 'A1001', 'BULK','A1001UK', '101' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC', 'A1002', 'BULK','A1001UK', '102' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC', 'A1003', 'BULK','A1001UK', '103' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC', 'A1004', 'BULK','A1001UK', '104' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC', 'A1005', 'BULK','A1001UK', '105'
    
    SELECT * FROM @IBM_SRC
```

```
DECLARE @TRANSACTION_HEADER TABLE (
    transaction_location_id VARCHAR (50),
    customer_account_id VARCHAR (50),
    transaction_type_code VARCHAR (50),
    IP_Short_Sku VARCHAR (50),
    TARGETID VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @TRANSACTION_HEADER
SELECT 'ABC', 'A1001', 'BULK','A1001UK', '101' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'A1002', 'BULK','A1001UK', '102' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'A1003', 'BULK','A1001UK', '103' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'A1004', 'REEL','A1001US', '104' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'A1005', 'BULK','A1001UK', '105'

SELECT * FROM @TRANSACTION_HEADER
```

if Driver have SRC_IBM than the script compare dataset for table SRC_IBM and TRANSACTION_HEADER based on mapping in Master table.
The Comparison will be based on sourceid and target id (Primary key of data table)

if Driver have SRC_ClickStream than the script compare dataset for table SRC_ClickStream and CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT based on mapping in Master table. The Comparison will be based on sourceID and targetID (Primary key of data table)

Result output

| SourceID | TargetID | Sourcetable_Name | Targettable_name | OrderType | transaction_type_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 104 | IBM_SRC | TRANSACTION_HEADER | 'BULK' | 'REEL' |

If anyone can suggest any alternate is highly appreciate.
how can we do this using **SQL or C#**.

Comment: "How to make this recon more dynamic" - whats a recon?

Comment: I have to say I am struggling to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @DaleK: I am very sorry for confussion. actually i am trying to compare data between source and target. as each source and target has different schema, so I am using Master table to get schema for source and target, and Driver table to know for which source comparison has to run. Please help.

Comment: Given that `@Table` variables are scoped to the current statement context (batch) I don't know how you plan to reference them from the dynamic SQL that something like this would require. Why isn't this something you'd want to implement in a client-side process rather than trying to kludge it into T-SQL?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Many Thanks. Can we do it using c# or python. Please help. i thought of client-side process, but don't know much how to used that. please help.

Comment: Are all source and data columns `VarChar` of some length? Comparing other types, or differing types (e.g. a `VarChar(19)` going to a `DateTime2(5)`), introduces some additional issues. How do you identify `SourceId` and `TargetId` columns from the available data? Are there always columns with those names?

Comment: @HABO: Thanks. Are all source and data columns VarChar of some length? : Yes.  How do you identify SourceId and TargetId columns from the available data? Are there always columns with those names? . Yes.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Table variable are just for example, which I going to replace with actual table.